# Change Language Facebook Share PHP, Zend

Tags: php, facebook

I have a PHP project with Zend Framework. and I want to add a Facebook Share option. The project has different Languages. English, Tagalog, Deutsch, France. etc. So what I want to do with my Facebook Share option is, whether the user selects any of this languages, for example the user is Tagalog, then the content of Facebook Share will also be in Tagalog as the user will share the website. Can anyone help me with this? I also heard that Facebook Share Option is deprecated in favor of the Like button, so any suggestion? actually the project already have a Like button. but I want to add the Share button every after the transaction has been made. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use a service like [AddThis](http://www.addthis.com/) or [ShareThis](http://sharethis.com/), they auto-translate and they make your life easier in general.